# How to combine same media queries inside single query in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, less, scss-mixins

I used to combine my media queries at one place in LESS like this

**LESS:**

```
.media-mixin(@break) when (@break = 1200px) {
  .abc{
       color: red;
  }
}
.media-mixin(@break) when (@break = 1200px) {
  .xyz{
       color: yellow;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .media-mixin(1200px);
}
```

**CSS result**

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .abc{
     color: red;
  }
  .xyz{
       color: yellow;
  }
}
```

How to convert the above mixin or What is the best way to do the same in SASS, I am unable to find a simple way so far.

Comment: According to [that comment](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/116#issuecomment-378779727) on the sass repository, grouping media queries isn't planned as sass is focussing on being a processor and not a compressor.

Comment: Why don't you just write one media query to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a simple way to do the same in Sass.

You could think of it in reverse and use a mixin with the media query inside:

```css
@mixin media-mixin($selector, $rule, $value) {
    @media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
        #{$selector} {
            #{$rule}: $value;
        }
    }
}

@include media-mixin(p, color, red);
```

---

Could also extend it to take a list of properties and values:

```css
@mixin media-mixin($selector, $rules...) {
    @media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
        #{$selector} {
            @each $rule in $rules {
                #{nth($rule, 1)}: nth($rule, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

@include media-mixin(p, (color, red), (background-color, blue));

/* More complex selectors need quotes */
@include media-mixin(".container > p", (color, red), (background-color, blue));
```